# Why am I getting "nan" values in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am making a Correlogram for an image. For each pixel, a correlogram finds the pixels of same color within a certain range of distance, d. Correlogram is a 2D matrix i.e. `correlogram[color][distance]`. The calculation of a Correlogram is somewhat similar to that of a Histogram.

**My Code:**  I am posting some major part of the code in which all the calculations are going on. Rest of the code (which i didn't post) is used to fulfill other condtions and therefore is not necessary.

**Problem:** In my final `correlogram[][]` , some values are "nan". I have checked the code but i am not able to find where is the problem in my calculation/syntax.

```
int ColorBins = 180;
int DistanceRange = 5;

double calcCorrelogram(Mat hsvImage)
{
    double correlogram[ColorBins][DistanceRange];
    int pixelNum[ColorBins]; //Used to count the number of pixels of same color

    Mat hsvPlanes[3];
    split(hsvImage, hsvPlanes);

    for(int pi=0; pi<hsvImage.rows; pi++)
    {
        for(int pj=0; pj<hsvImage.cols; pj++)
        {
            int pixelColor = (int)hsvPlanes[0].at<uchar>(pi,pj);
            pixelNum[pixelColor]++; 

            for(int d=1; d<=DistanceRange; d++)
            {
                int sameColorNum=0; //* number of pixels with same color in the d-distance boundary */
                int totalBoundaryNum=0; //* total number of pixels in the d-distance boundary */

                for(int i= pi-d, j= pj-d; j<=pj+d; j++)
                {
                    if(i<0)
                        break;
                    if(j<0 || j>=hsvImage.cols)
                        continue;

                    int neighbourColor  = (int)hsvPlanes[0].at<uchar>(i,j);
                    if(pixelColor == neighbourColor)
                    {
                        sameColorNum++;
                    }
                    totalBoundaryNum++;

                    correlogram[pixelColor][d-1] = correlogram[pixelColor][d-1] + (double)sameColorNum / (double)totalBoundaryNum;
            }   
        } 
    }

    for(int c=0; c<ColorBins; c++)
    {
        for(int d=0; d<DistanceRange; d++)
        {
            if(pixelNum[c] != 0)
                correlogram[c][d] = correlogram[c][d] / (double)pixelNum[c];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably dividing by zero in ` correlogram[c][d] / (double)pixelNum[c]` -- looking at the code im not convinced that every element in pixelNum is assigned a proper value.

Comment: @Soren: Please have a look at the last part of the code, there is a `if` statement (`if(pixelNum[c] != 0)`) before dividing by `pixelNum[c]`.

Answer (score 5):

NaNs are generally created when you divide zero by zero or multiply zero by infinity.  One easy way to check for abnormal numbers like NaN and infinity is to multiply by zero and check if the result is zero:

```
bool is_valid_double(double x)
{
    return x*0.0==0.0;
}
```

This will return false if `x` is either NaN or infinity.

Then you can sprinkle your code with assertions to help find where things are going wrong:

```
assert(is_valid_double(correlogram[c][d]));
```

Once you get a crash due to an assertion failure, you can use the debugger to look at the state of the program to help determine what is going on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Somebody (with higher points) wrote: "Those who can use debugger, never asks at SO". Anyways, i am still trying to figure out the problem.

Comment: @skm: If you can't use a debugger, you can try printing out values to help you get an understanding of the problem.

Comment: Yeah, you have given a nice idea above. I am trying to use your `bool` thing to find the values which are creating problem.

Comment: As per your suggestion, i used the `is_valid_double()` to find out those values due to which i am getting `nan`. I found that some values in `correlogram[c][d]` were already `nan`. Now, i have initialized all the elements of `correlogram[c][d]` to Zero through `for loops`. After this, i am not getting `nan` anymore but do you think that could be the real reason of problem? I think that when we declare an array then, C++ itself assign `zero` to all the elements if then are not explicitly initialized...isn't?

Comment: @skm: It is certainly possible. Arrays are not initialized to zero by default. Any use of an uninitialized value causes undefined behavior, so initializing is a good idea in general.

Comment: I am not sure that it will really solve the problem because i am using the similar code in another program but i am still getting the `nan` there.

Comment: skm, - oh dear, i promise to *never* make such daring/arrogant statements again ;)

Comment: @berak: hahaha that statement is true and i did not find any arrogance in it. I am surprised that you still remember your old statement and coincidentally also read my comment here  ;)

Comment: Some compilers will give false for (a==a) if a is nan. Might be faster than multiplication!